# Why pass by pointer when we can pass the variable's address with the & operator?

Tags: c, function, pointers

As C doesn't support pass by reference, when we write functions that make changes to the values of parameters we take pointers as parameters. For example:

```
void swap(int *ptr1, int *ptr2)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;
}
```

When calling this function I can either pass two pointers or pass the variables with the `&` operator, like `swap(ptr1, ptr2)` or `swap(&num1, &num2)`, although the function is written to accept pointers.

Does it make any difference if I pass the address directly instead of passing a pointer? How should I decide in which way I should pass the parameters to such a function?

Comment: How did you initialize `ptr1`? I'm guessing `int *ptr1 = &num1;` or equivalent.

Comment: If you need to pass some `int` value, say 78, to a function, do you write `foo(78);` or `int t = 78; foo(t);`? This is the same thing. If you do not need a variable and it will not make things clearer for the reader, do not use one.

Comment: Yes. That's how I initialized both the ptr1 and ptr2 pointers.

Comment: The result of the `&` operator is a pointer

Comment: So, they're effectively equivalent. The same value is passed as a parameter regardless of which you use, namely the address of `num1`. When should you use the `ptr1` variant? When it's useful in your calling procedure to have the address of `num1` for some other purpose, beyond this swap usage. In most cases, it's simpler and clearer to simply pass `&num1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer *is* (the type of) an address. I don't know why you use the two words as if they're different things.

When you call `f(&x)` first `&x` creates **a pointer** containing the memory address of `x` (AKA 'pointing to `x`'), and passes that into the function. It's the exact same thing as `int* p = &x; f(p)` (assuming the type of `x` is `int`).

This is no different than `g(42)` vs `int i = 42; g(i)`, as Eric Postpischil mentions. They are the same thing - temporary vs named variables.

Comment: This answer isn't inaccurate but I don't think it's sufficiently clarifying, and possibly misleading. `&x` doesn't "create a pointer". It's not a "temporary variable", just an expression. Eric's analogy you cite is a lot more helpful.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I think at a more fundamental level it is clarifying, and the only objection to my usage of 'temporary variable' vs 'expression' comes from a language lawyer perspective that is not useful to OP.

Comment: The conceptual difference between "temporary variable" and "expression" is really important and is not just language lawyering. It's mostly analogous to the difference between lvalue and rvalue.